# how to access new manuplated combined columns in MVC asp.net using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am facing problem in displaying the column field value at the view.

I am returning view like follows.

```
var TicketList = (from T in db.Tickets
                  where  T.Title.Contains("a")
                  select new {
                        customerName = (
                             from cname in db.Customers
                             where cname.CustomerId == T.CustomersId
                             select cname.FirstName + cname.LastName
                        ) ,
                        Title = T.Title
                  }).ToList();

 return View("SearchTicketsResult",TicketList);
```

and at the view page I have

```
<%foreach (TicketList ti in (IEnumerable)ViewData.Model) {%>
    <%=ti.Title%><br />
    <%=ti.customerName %>
<% } %>
```

I am not able to list customername or the title in the page. It says "The type or namespace name 'TicketList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Can someone guide me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"TicketList" is the *variable* name for a list of an anonymous type. There is no "TicketList" type. Casting from anonymous types can be done ("by example"), but is **very** brittle, and I simply don't recommend you use an anonymous type for this.

One option would be to declare my own type (in the UI's "model(s)" folder) - for example `TicketSummary` / `TicketLite` (etc), with a `Title` and `CustomerName`. Then use *this* type:

```
public class TicketSummary
{

     public string CustomerName { get; set; }
     public string Title { get; set; }
}

var ticketList = (from t in db.Tickets
                  where  t.Title.Contains("a")
                  select new TicketSummary
                  {
                      CustomerName = (
                          from cname in db.Customers
                          where cname.CustomerId == t.CustomersId
                          select cname.FirstName.ToString()
                      ).FirstOrDefault(),
                      Title = t.Title
                  }).ToList();
return ticketList;
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
<%foreach (TicketSummary ts in (IEnumerable<TicketSummary>)ViewData.Model) {%>
    <%=ts.Title%><br />
    <%=ts.customerName %>
<% } %>
```

In reality, I'd probably offload this work to a repository, and have a repository method that returns a list of the summary type.

Comment: I have created TicketSummary.cs in Models folder with following properties.
public class TicketSummary
{
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
........
}

I think I am not doing it right ?

Comment: Did you also change the query "new TicketSummary {...}" and the view ("foreach (TicketSummary ...")

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am still not able to get it.
I created ITicketsRepositiory interfece IEnumerable<Ticket> ListTickets();
then TicketSummary as Repository file with TicketSummary : ITicketsRepositiory
and in that file I have

Comment: public IEnumerable ListTickets()
        {       var TicketList = (from T in db.Tickets select new { customerName = (from cname in db.Customers where cname.CustomerId == T.CustomersId select cname.FirstName.ToString()), Title = T.Title }
).ToList(); return TicketList;

Comment: ERROR:TicketSummary' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'CRM.Models.TicketSummary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly

Comment: TicketSummary only needs to have the properties you are projecting; Title and CustomerName... class TicketSummary { public string Title {get;set;} public string CustomerName {get;set;} }

Comment: No, don't "select new {" - you ***need*** to use your type: "select new TicketSummary {"

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, but unable to arrange where and how 
select new {" - you ***need*** to use your type: "select new TicketSummary 

I have uploaded files at http://ade-technologies.com/crm.rar
I hope you can quickly modify it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated - does that help at all? I can't really test further since there is no csproj etc in the rar

Comment: where I can find the updates. Anyway I have uploaded all the files including database sql at the place. you can check it now.

Comment: Hey :) 

It worked.....

Thanks a million. I really really thankful to you.
Thank you so much for your time and efforts. Do let me know if I can do anything for you. 

You can MSN with me at anilmane@hotmail.com